# Настройка галереи плагин Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Не получается настроить галерею, чтобы она выглядела вот таким образом:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код html:

```
  <div class="container-fluid no-gutters">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="grid-item col-6">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-6">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                </div>
    </div>
```

Код JS:

```
var grid = $(".grid");
    grid.imagesLoaded(function(){
        grid.isotope({
            columnWidth: ".grid-item",
            itemSelector: ".grid-item",
            gutter: 5
        });
        $('.grid-item').imagefill(); 
    });
```

Стили CSS:

```
.grid-item
    height: 40vh
    margin-bottom: 15px
img
    width: 100%
```

Необходимо чтобы между плитками оставалось расстояние